# Difficult logarithmic integral: $\int_0^\Lambda r^{d - 1}\log(1 + a\sqrt{r^2 + m_1^2} + b\sqrt{r^2 + m_2^2}) dr$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I'm working on QFT's, and encountered the following integral
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I = \int_0^\Lambda r^{d - 1}\log(1 + a\sqrt{r^2 + m_1^2} + b\sqrt{r^2 + m_2^2}) dr \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $a, b, m_1, m_2$ are real, non-zero parameters all different from each other, and $\Lambda > 1$. (I expect the integral to be divergent in the $\Lambda\rightarrow\infty$ limit.) I'm wondering if anyone here can help me perform this integration. I believe it might be useful to differentiate w.r.t. $a$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \int_0^\Lambda \frac{r^{d - 1}\sqrt{r^2 + m_1^2}}{1 + a\sqrt{r^2 + m_1^2} + b\sqrt{r^2 + m_2^2}} dr \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I tried to do these integrations in Mathematica, but it wasn't able to do it. That said, if you know a program that can do these integrals that's good enough. Moreover, finding a primitive function is probably also good enough.

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: My two cents. You might want to consider the integral $$I(a,b,c)=\int_{0}^{\Lambda}r^{d-1}\log \left(c+a\sqrt{r^{2}+m_{1}^{2}}+b\sqrt{r^{2}+m_{2}^{2}} \right) dr$$ instead, noting you care about $I(a,b,1)$. By differentiating under the integral for each coordinate and manipulating, you should find the integral satisfies the PDE $$aI_{a}+bI_{b}+cI_{c}=\frac{\Lambda^{d}}{d}$$ which has general solution $$I=\frac{\Lambda^{d}}{d}\ln(a+b+c)+f\left(\frac{a}{b},\frac{a+b}{c}\right)$$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$. However, you need to know $I$ to determine $f$ which is a problem.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! Do you think it's possible to find the function $f$ if I know some boundary conditions on $I(a, b, c)$? E.g. I've managed to compute $I(0, b, c)$ and $I(a, 0, c)$ prior to this integral.

Comment: If you know $I(0,b,c)$ and $I(a,0,c)$ then I'm pretty sure you can uniquely determine $f$. It would mean that we would need to change our $f$ above though as $I(a, 0, c)$ would be giving initial data along a characteristic curve _that I had chosen to be constant_. We can just take a different characteristic by solving different ODEs, for example let $$f \left(\frac{a}{b},\frac{a+b}{c}\right)\to f\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c}\right)$$ which works with your known integrals. Maybe add those integrals to your post and I'll try and derive the solution as well and we can compare our results.

Comment: $(+1)$ on the question by the way, I've found it very interesting.

Comment: Thanks! I find it more interesting after you made the connection with the PDE. By the way, how did you find this PDE? Is it related to the method of characteristics or something?

I haven't found the integral with $b=0$ yet, but I'm not sure if it's even needed. I.e. isn't it possible to iterate this process? That is, we can study the following integral first
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I(a,b) = \int_0 \Lambda r^{d - 1}\log(a + b\sqrt{r^2 + m^2}) \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: This integral satisfies the following PDE
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
aI_a + bI_b = \frac{\Lambda^d}{d} \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which has the solution
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I(a, b) = \frac{\Lambda^d}{d}\log(a) + f(\frac{b}{a}) \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where the first term is $I(a, 0)$. How can I determine the function $f(x)$ for this integral? It should be fairly simple to find several boundary conditions from e.g. $I(0, b)$.

Comment: I just realized that $f(x)$ can be found from $I(1, x)$, but this is the same as just factoring out the $a$ from the logarithm. I can find this one, but it's a bit nasty. I'll try to see if it can be simplified. Maybe it can be used to determine $f(x,y)$ in the integral $I(a,b,c)$?

Comment: I found the PDE by noticing that after differentiating under the integral sign with respect to $a$ and then multiplying both sides by $a$, you get one of the terms in the denominator $\left(a \sqrt{r^{2}+m_{1}^{2}} \right)$ in the numerator. Doing the same to the other coordinates and summing yields a PDE on the LHS and an easily integrated function on the RHS. This is a reasonably well known approach to solving integrals with parameters. The [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) is the method you use to solve the PDE because it is _first order_.

Comment: Also, there is nothing to iterate. It seem you are trying to 'reduce' the PDE and make it simpler by setting one of the parameters attached to one of the square root functions to be zero in the hope that we can use this information to help solve our problem, but it doesn't work like that. Your approach also still leaves you with the exact same problem of needing to know a value of the integral in order to determine $f$ (and you can't use $I(0, b)$ as you suggested with the characteristic $b/a = C_{1}$).

Comment: I was wondering whether one could use some b.c.'s on $f$ to determine it, but maybe this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, with $\Lambda$ there, you are just asking for the indefinite integral.

Why do you want it in closed form?  Don't you think leaving it in integral form is more useful?

With $d=a=b=1$, Maple finds an answer.  It is long.  It involves
arctan, atanh, elliptic integrals $E$, $\Pi$, and $F$.  Here it is an Maple notation:

`1/2/(-m[1]^2+(2*m[2]+2)*m[1]-(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)*(1/4*I*(m[2]^(1/2)*m[1]^2-2*m[2] ^(3/2)*m[1]-m[2]^(1/2)+m[2]^(5/2))*(-m[1]^2+(2*m[2]+2)*m[1]-(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)* EllipticPi(I*r/m[1]^(1/2),-4*m[1]/(m[1]^2+(-2*m[2]-2)*m[1]+(m[2]-1)^2),1/m[2]^( 1/2)*m[1]^(1/2))+(-1/4*m[2]*(arctanh((r*(m[1]^2+(-2*m[2]-2)*m[1]+(m[2]-1)^2)^(1 /2)-2*m[1])/(r^2+m[1])^(1/2)/(m[1]-m[2]+1))+arctanh((r*(m[1]^2+(-2*m[2]-2)*m[1] +(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)+2*m[1])/(r^2+m[1])^(1/2)/(m[1]-m[2]+1))-arctanh((r*(m[1]^2+( -2*m[2]-2)*m[1]+(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)-2*m[2])/(r^2+m[2])^(1/2)/(m[1]-m[2]-1))- arctanh((r*(m[1]^2+(-2*m[2]-2)*m[1]+(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)+2*m[2])/(r^2+m[2])^(1/2)/ (m[1]-m[2]-1)))*(m[1]^2+(-2*m[2]-2)*m[1]+(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)+2*ln(1+(r^2+m[1])^(1 /2)+(r^2+m[2])^(1/2))*r*m[2]+((-I+1/2*I*m[1])*m[2]^(3/2)-1/4*I*m[2]^(5/2)+(1/4* I-1/4*I*m[1]^2)*m[2]^(1/2))*EllipticF(I*r/m[1]^(1/2),1/m[2]^(1/2)*m[1]^(1/2))+I *EllipticE(I*r/m[1]^(1/2),1/m[2]^(1/2)*m[1]^(1/2))*m[2]^(3/2)-m[2]*((-1/2*m[1]+ 1/2*m[2]-1/2)*ln(r+(r^2+m[1])^(1/2))+(1/2*m[1]-1/2*m[2]-1/2)*ln(r+(r^2+m[2])^(1 /2))+r))*(-m[1]^2+(2*m[2]+2)*m[1]-(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)-1/2*(m[2]^2+(-2*m[1]-2)*m[2 ]+(m[1]-1)^2)*m[2]*arctan(2*r/(-m[1]^2+(2*m[2]+2)*m[1]-(m[2]-1)^2)^(1/2)))/m[2]`

Note `m[1]` and `m[2]` are $m_1, m_2$.  Assumptions were: $m_1 > m_2+1, m_2 > 0$.

If I try $d=2$, Maple does not solve it.
If I try $d=1$ but $a,b$ merely positive, Maple solves it.  But even in Maple notation its length exceeds $10^6$.

Comment: Eventually I wish to expand the integral around large $\Lambda$.

For the specific case I'm considering $d = 3 - \epsilon$, where $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$ is a small parameter. In principle we can expand the integrand in $\epsilon$ first and integrate the terms upto $\epsilon$, but I don't think this will be easier.